# Possible to disable download of issuer certificates in SslStream?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, sslstream

When using an `SslStream` to connect to an internal, trusted server using a self-signed CA certificate, I want to disable automatic downloading of issuer certificates.

The reason is that the certificate is broken in a way that it points to an invalid network location and thus stalls the connection for about 10 seconds on (almost) every SSL handshake.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using a certificate call back function? if the cert being loaded is the 'dodgy' one I guess you could redirect there?

Comment: Unfortuately, the cert chain resolution is done *before* that callback is being called. It seems the actual resolution is done in CAPI in native code

Comment: How can the self-signed certificate require search for the issuer certificate?

Comment: Clarification: the CA cert is self-signed.